# I'am trying to use the google Forms API. But there is a reference error

Tags: javascript, google-forms, referenceerror

I'm trying to use the Google Form API. When I'm trying to use `FormApp.openByUrl()`. But I'm getting an `ReferenceError`. Here is my code:

I already tried to import the API. But it didn't work.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/SOME-FORM/edit');
        var formResponses = form.getResponses();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console output:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FormApp is not defined
    at (index):9
(anonymous) @ (index):9
```

It should just do nothing, but it's throwing an exception.

Comment: The error message and stack trace would be useful

Comment: you have to include the right js file

Comment: @DanielA.White and where do I get them from??

Comment: In this JS file there is nothing called `FormApp`.

Comment: @TheGreydiamond ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ you’ll have to read the documentation

Comment: @TheGreydiamond The same as Daniel. That this is the wrong JS file you are using.

Comment: I downloaded the script in the question.  Indeed, it does not contain `FormApp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you are trying to use is for scripts embedded into a Google Form via the Script Editor.

[image: screenshot]

It has nothing to do with the script `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` which is for connecting to Google APIs from other websites.

Comment: Thank you for the clearifiication here. I was already curious why I couldn't find some CDN to add and test whether the OP's idea works at all.